# Отправка POST запроса на верификацию FastAPIUsers

Tags: python, fastapi

```
async def veryfiy_request():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        r = await client.post(f'http://0.0.0.0:8000/auth/request-verify-token', 
                                  params={"email": "user@example.com"})
        print(r.content)
        print(r.status_code)

class UserManager(UUIDIDMixin, BaseUserManager[User, uuid.UUID]):
    reset_password_token_secret = SECRET
    verification_token_secret = SECRET

    async def on_after_register(self, user: User, request: Optional[Request] = None):
        print(f"User {user.id} has registered.")
        await veryfiy_request()


    async def on_after_forgot_password(
        self, user: User, token: str, request: Optional[Request] = None
    ):
        print(f"User {user.id} has forgot their password. Reset token: {token}")

    async def on_after_request_verify(
        self, user: User, token: str, request: Optional[Request] = None
    ):
        print(f"Verification requested for user {user.id}. Verification token: {token}")
```

Всем здравья. У меня следующая проблема: функция veryfiy_request должна передавать почту пользователя который только что зарегистрировался, а метод привязанный on_after_request_verify к соответствующему маршруту должен присылать токен для подтверждения пользователя. Вместо этого получаю:

> INFO:     127.0.0.1:51170 - "POST
> /auth/request-verify-token?email=user%40example.com HTTP/1.1" 422
> Unprocessable Entity
> b'{"detail":[{"type":"missing","loc":["body","email"],"msg":"Field
> required","input":null,"url":"https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.2/v/missing"}]}'
> 422

Работаю с бибилотекой fastapi users

Comment: Наверное, отсылать надо не через `params=`, а через `json=`

Comment: https://www.python-httpx.org/api/#helper-functions

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov спасибо